# How to make screen sharing work on sway/wayland ? For noobies

Tags: wayland, sway

I'm new to sway/wayland and I'm trying to make screensharing work on chrome. So far I've installed `pipewire` `xdg-desktop-portal` and `xdg-desktop-portal-wlr`. I've set the `chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-pipewire-capturer` flag to enabled and I've created the following `~/.config/environment.d/.conf` file

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=sway
```

Now from my understanding I need to import the `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `WAYLAND_DISPLAY` variables. How can I do this on startup?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the screen sharing didn't work because I didn't have `pipewire-media-session` installed

Comment: Note that `wireplumber` is more recommended as of 2023.